# Show uniqueness of Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

Consider the following optimisation problem

$$
(1) \quad \min_{x\geq 0} a^\top x+ \epsilon ||x||_2,\\
\quad \quad \quad \text{s.t. }B^\top x=c
$$
with $\epsilon>0$.

Suppose I assume that linear independence constraint qualification (LICQ) holds. That is, for every $x\in \{x\in \mathbb{R}^: x\geq 0, B^\top x=c\}$, the binding constraints are linearly independent.

Consider the Lagrangian of (1):
$$
L(x,\mu,v)=a^\top x+ \epsilon ||x||_2-\nu^\top x+\mu^\top(B^\top x-c)
$$

Consider the sets of $x$ and $\mu$ satisfying the KKT conditions. Let me call these sets $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ respectively.

**Question:** could you help to show that $\mathcal{X}$ **and** $\mathcal{M}$ are singleton?

**Thoughts**: I believe that $\mathcal{X}$ is singleton because $\epsilon ||x||_2$ is strictly convex. Instead, I cannot show why $\mathcal{M}$ is singleton.

Comment: Can you list the KKT conditions? You should be able to use them to show that $\mathcal{M}$ is singleton, similar to my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084561/strictly-convex-linear-programming-linear-independence-constraint-qualification).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try but I'm not sure I'll manage. Please answer if you have time. BTW, is my definition of LICQ above correct?

Comment: Where is the linear program?